# How to make an argument optional based upon another argument's value in Python using click?

Tags: python, python-click

I have this following CLI method that I have created using `click` module in python.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("name")
@click.option("--provider", "-p", default="aws", help="Cloud Provider")
@click.argument("view", required=True)

def create(name, view, provider):
   print name
   print view
   print provider

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()
```

I want to manipulate `view` option based on the value it gets for `--provider`. For example if `--provider` is `aws` then `required=True` for `view` else `required=False` making `view` optional while running my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for anything fancy, something like this will work

```
def create(name, provider, view=None):
    if provider == "aws" and view is None:
        raise AttributeError("View is required when provider is 'aws'")
```

Comment: Or you could use a `click.exit("some appropriate message")` rather than an exception.

Comment: when I tried this I got a SyntaxError:

`def create(name, view=None, provider):
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`

Comment: @ANIL Make sure the `view=None` is the last thing in your argument list.